# to_csv does not generate desired output of data frame converted from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe

I have a list of data frame `output` as below:

```
[           contig                             read_name  position reference_kmer  event_level_mean  event_stdv       count
0    gblock_Gmod2  12212f92-6610-410a-b317-bc2ca3f57f99         1          CACAT         78.400000    1.079000    15.04458
1    gblock_Gmod2  12212f92-6610-410a-b317-bc2ca3f57f99         2          ACATC         84.570000    1.173000    10.02972
2    gblock_Gmod2  12212f92-6610-410a-b317-bc2ca3f57f99         3          CATCA        101.207332   13.997181   106.30899
3    gblock_Gmod2  12212f92-6610-410a-b317-bc2ca3f57f99        13          TACCC         80.260000    2.824000    11.02665
4    gblock_Gmod2  12212f92-6610-410a-b317-bc2ca3f57f99        14          ACCCG         69.084390    1.138712    27.06816
5    gblock_Gmod2  12212f92-6610-410a-b317-bc2ca3f57f99        15          CCCGG         75.963461    2.477512    31.08609
.
.
.]
```

I want to write this list to file. So I first converted the list to data frame and write to a file name `out.txt`. I executed the commands below:

```
result = pandas.DataFrame(output)
result.to_csv('out.txt', index=False, sep = "\t")
```

However, the head of tail of the file `out.txt` showed extra `0` and double quotation `"`.

```
0
"           contig                             read_name  position reference_kmer  event_level_mean  event_stdv       count
0    gblock_Gmod2  12212f92-6610-410a-b317-bc2ca3f57f99         1          CACAT         78.400000    1.079000    15.04458
1    gblock_Gmod2  12212f92-6610-410a-b317-bc2ca3f57f99         2          ACATC         84.570000    1.173000    10.02972
2    gblock_Gmod2  12212f92-6610-410a-b317-bc2ca3f57f99         3          CATCA        101.207332   13.997181   106.30899
3    gblock_Gmod2  12212f92-6610-410a-b317-bc2ca3f57f99        13          TACCC         80.260000    2.824000    11.02665
4    gblock_Gmod2  12212f92-6610-410a-b317-bc2ca3f57f99        14          ACCCG         69.084390    1.138712    27.06816
5    gblock_Gmod2  12212f92-6610-410a-b317-bc2ca3f57f99        15          CCCGG         75.963461    2.477512    31.08609
.
.
."
```

How do I get rid of the `0` and `"`? Thanks.

Comment: How many dataframe `output` contains? If it is a single dataframe, try `pandas.DataFrame(output[0])`

Comment: @Chris I got it. Thanks.